How to extract filename without extension in Makefile
Below is my Makefile where I want to generate a PDF from an .adoc:
SHELL := /bin/bash

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

# version and build for the target
VERSION := 1.0.0
BUILD := `git rev-parse HEAD`

# source directory
SRCDIR := ${CURDIR}/src

# create output directory
OUTDIR := ${CURDIR}/build
MAKE_OUTDIR = $(shell mkdir -p $(OUTDIR))

.PHONY: all build-html build-pdf clean

build: $(MAKE_OUTDIR) build-html build-pdf

build-html:
    @$(foreach file, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.adoc), asciidoctor \
        -r asciidoctor-diagram \
        -o $(OUTDIR)/html/$(file%.*)_$(VERSION) $(file);)

build-pdf:
    @$(foreach file, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.adoc), asciidoctor-pdf \
        -r asciidoctor-diagram \
        -o $(OUTDIR)/html/$(file%.*)_$(VERSION) $(file);)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(OUTDIR)

Problem is that the output filename is just _1_0_0 (the version)... and the base filename doesn't get extracted. What am I missing?

What do you expect $(file%.*) to do, actually?  Whatever you expect, that's not what it does.  This expands the make variable named, literally, file%.*.  That variable does not exist, so it expands to the empty string.

If using GNU Make, it has a basename function.

Your use of make is quite unusual. make is not a scripting language. All it does is based on product-dependencies relations. And its recipes are already shell scripts, there is no reason to use the shell make function in a recipe. Never. A more traditional way to use GNU make in your case could be something like:
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

# version and build for the target
VERSION := 1.0.0
BUILD   := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)

# source directory
SRCDIR := $(CURDIR)/src

# source files
ADOCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.adoc)

# output directory
OUTDIR := $(CURDIR)/build

# output files
HTMLS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.adoc,$(OUTDIR)/html/%_$(VERSION).html,$(ADOCS))
PDFS  := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.adoc,$(OUTDIR)/html/%_$(VERSION).pdf,$(ADOCS))

.PHONY: all clean build build-html build-pdf

all: build
build: build-html build-pdf
build-html: $(HTMLS)
build-pdf: $(PDFS)

$(HTMLS): $(OUTDIR)/html/%_$(VERSION).html: $(SRCDIR)/%.adoc | $(OUTDIR)/html
    asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-diagram -o $@ $<

$(PDFS): $(OUTDIR)/html/%_$(VERSION).pdf: $(SRCDIR)/%.adoc  | $(OUTDIR)/html
    asciidoctor-pdf -r asciidoctor-diagram -o $@ $<

$(OUTDIR)/html:
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OUTDIR)

It is not only more traditional, it has 2 main advantages:

If a target (HTML or PDF) is up to date it will not be rebuilt.
If you have, say 12 cores, and you use the -j12 option of make, it will run up to 12 jobs in parallel.


Thank u very much, it helped a lot.

Here's how I solved the issue:
build-html:
    @$(foreach file, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.adoc), asciidoctor \
        -r asciidoctor-diagram \
        -o $(OUTDIR)/html/$(shell basename -s .adoc $(file))_$(VERSION).html $(file);)

I worked also with regex... but the command was too long in my opinion.

Your use of make is quite unusual. make is not a scripting language. All it does is based on product-dependencies relations. And its recipes are already shell scripts, there is no reason to use the shell make function in a recipe. Never. My answer shows a more traditional way to use GNU make in your case. Note: you store your HTML and PDF files in a directory named html. If it is a typo you will have to change a few things.
